# Get True or False comparing images with Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I made a code, who takes screenshots, and compares with a target image, when then are equal, it clicks on a specific place on the screen, but, the both images is equal but the program gets false always

The code:

```
import time
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageChops

def wait(secs):
    time.sleep(secs)

def Screenshot_Taker(path, l, t, r, b):

    wait(2)

    image = pyautogui.screenshot()

    box = (l, t, r, b)

    image = image.crop(box)

    image.save(path, format = "png")
```

```
def Image_Compare_Click(Image1, Image2, l, t, r, b, x, y):

    image1 = Image.open(Image1).convert("RGB")
    image2 = Image.open(Image2).convert("RGB")

    while True:

        diff = ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)

        if diff.getbbox():
            print("Images are not the same")
            Screenshot_Taker(Image1, l, t, r, b)
            pyautogui.moveTo(x = 1365, y = 767)
            continue

        else:
            print("Images are the same")
            wait(1)
            pyautogui.click(x = x, y = y)
            wait(1)
            pyautogui.moveTo(x = 1365, y = 767)
            break
```

When I run:

```
Screenshot_Taker(path = "Image1.png",
l = 320, t = 550, r = 370, b = 610)

Image_Compare_Click(Image1 = "Image1.png", "Image2.png", 
l = 320, t = 550, r = 370, b = 610, x = 345, y = 580)
```

The output is:

```
Images are not the same
Images are not the same
Images are not the same
Images are not the same
Images are not the same
```

Comment: In your own words, why should `image1` or `image2` ever change when the loop runs? If these were not the same image before the loop started, and they do not change, how could they ever become the same image? (Aside from that, keep in mind that it may be very difficult to get *exactly* the target image from a screenshot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are comparing the same old two images. In your `Image_Compare_Click`, you need to do the following:

```py
def Image_Compare_Click(Image1, Image2, l, t, r, b, x, y):

    # image1 = Image.open(Image1).convert("RGB") # <-- commented this
    image2 = Image.open(Image2).convert("RGB")

    while True:
        image1 = Image.open(Image1).convert("RGB") #<-- added this
        diff = ImageChops.difference(image1, image2)
        ...
```